# how do I solve namespace conflict in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I use Win7 system with Visual Studio 2010. I'm using OpenCV and there is a embedded flann namespace.

But I also used an original FLANN packagehttp://people.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN.

I follow the user manual to compile the FLANN by using

```
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
> cd flann-x.y.z-src
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ..
```

I added the FLANN folder in my VS2010 project:
c++ folder->include directories

So when I write C++ code and want to using "flann" namespace, there is an namespace conflict error.

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have `using namespace` anywhere in your code?

Comment: The problem is, I have to use both opencv namespace and flann namespace. But there is also a flann.hpp in opencv. So "flann" is conflict.

Comment: Should you be using two different version of Flann anyway?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're saying.  When you say there's a namespace conflict error, is that a compiler error?  Can you show us the whole error message from the Output Window (not the Error Window, that just has summaries).

Comment: @Aesthete: presumably he doesn't want to use the OpenCV Flann, and is using the other to replace it.

Comment: the opencv flann has less function, so I have to use the original flann package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably most reliable solution is to rename one of namespaces. You said that you have compiled `flann` - in a such case, you can rename it's namespace, and recompile again.

Maybe you can reuse [Boost.BCP tool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html#bcp.syntax) with small modification - it has namespace rename feature.

Or if you see some common pattern in `flann` - then you can try to rename it just by simple global search-and-replace. After renaming, do `diff` to be sure that only needed parts are renamed, and do `grep` to be sure that all needed places are renamed.

---

Another option is to define preprocessor macro during compilation of `flann` which would rename namespace, like:

```
#define flann flann_vanilla
```

and add it to compiler options like:

```
-Dflann=flann_vanilla
```

At this case, you should wrap inclusion of every `flann` header to:

```
#define flann flann_vanilla
#include "flann.hpp"
#undef flann
```

---

Also, if those duplicated namespaces are from same library (maybe different versions) - be aware of possible preprocessor macro clash, especially clash of include guards. Easiest solution for include guards clash is to use implementation-specific `#pragma once`.

Comment: Do you mean the best way is that, I modify the source code of FLANN and recompile it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't know any better and reliable solution to do this. Maybe you could find ways to workaround some of problems, but note - as both use same namespace name - there is possible symbol clash across translation units and the result [ODR violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the existing 'flann' namespace in a new namespace, then refer to it using fully qualified syntax.